# How to make a toggle button in javascript to change the backgrounds of divs, text of a <p> tag and switch between two groups of divs

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been working on this project for a few days where I would like to toggle several elements of a page to hide and make others appear. This happens with the use of the button you see before you. The button successfully changes the page to the other but I am unable to bring it back to the other setting. I change the backgrounds with the use of data- values in the divs. The problem is I have a limited understanding of javascript and am sure that my code is probably riddled with problems. So in conclusion I would like the button to be able to toggle between both states of the page. I am also willing to use JQuery which there is some of already in my code. As a last note I would also like to later add css transitions later if that would change anyones answer or if anyone could provide any advice on that before i do it that would be great.

> This is a sample of the HTML of one of the divs. This particular one contains the button that toggles and the divs that I want to switch out

```
<div class="container-projects bg-topics color-div" data-color="#383838" data-color1="#A2AB58">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 id="projects" class="text-center">TOPICS</h1>
            <br />
            <br />

            <div class="row" id="goodPageTopics">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled text-center">
                        <li class="filter btn btn-primary" data-filter="all">ALL</li>
                        <li class="filter btn btn-primary" data-filter=".branding">POLITICS</li>
                        <li class="filter btn btn-primary" data-filter=".design">ETHICS</li>
                        <li class="filter btn btn-primary" data-filter=".development">MISCALULATIONS</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="mix branding col-md-3" id="goodTopic1">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/projects/project1.png" />
                        <a href="#project-1">
                            <div class="img-info bg-primary">Click to see more info</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mix development col-md-3" id="goodTopic2">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/projects/project2.png" />
                        <a href="#project-2">
                            <div class="img-info bg-success">Click to see more info</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mix design col-md-3" id="goodTopic3">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/projects/project3.png" />
                        <a href="#project-3">
                            <div class="img-info bg-warning">Click to see more info</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mix branding col-md-3" id="goodTopic4">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/projects/project4.png" />
                        <a href="#project-4">
                            <div class="img-info bg-danger">Click to see more info</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mix design col-md-3" id="goodTopic5">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/projects/project5.png" />
                        <a href="#project-5">
                            <div class="img-info bg-info">Click to see more info</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mix seo col-md-3" id="goodTopic6">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/projects/project6.png" />
                        <a href="#project-6">
                            <div class="img-info bg-primary">Click to see more info</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mix design col-md-3" id="goodTopic7">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/projects/project7.png" />
                        <a href="#project-7">
                            <div class="img-info bg-success">Click to see more info</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="mix seo col-md-3" id="goodTopic8">
                    <div class="img-wrapper">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/projects/project8.png" />
                        <a href="#project-8">
                            <div class="img-info bg-warning">Click to see more info</div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix hidden-xs" style="width:100%; height:50px;"></div>
        <div class="btn-switchbutton-container">
            <button type="button" class="btn-switchbutton color-div" id="change-page" data-color="#9a0707" data-color1="">Change Veiw</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> This is a sample of a div that replaces the others but is hidden by default

```
<div class="mix development col-md-3" id="badTopic1">
        <div class="img-wrapper">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="images/backfiletest.png" />
            <a href="#project-2">
                <div class="img-info bg-success">Click to see more info</div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> This is the code before I started messing with it but sadly it is unable to toggle.

```
$('body').on('click', '#change-page', function () {
            $('.color-div').each(function () {
                $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('color'));
            });
            // Changes the topics
            $('#badTopic1, #badTopic2, #badTopic3, #badTopic4, #badTopic5, #badTopic6, #badTopic7, #badTopic8').each(function () {
                $('#badTopic1, #badTopic2, #badTopic3, #badTopic4, #badTopic5, #badTopic6, #badTopic7, #badTopic8').show();
                $("#goodTopic1").replaceWith($("#badTopic1"));
                $("#goodTopic2").replaceWith($("#badTopic2"));
                $("#goodTopic3").replaceWith($("#badTopic3"));
                $("#goodTopic4").replaceWith($("#badTopic4"));
                $("#goodTopic5").replaceWith($("#badTopic5"));
                $("#goodTopic6").replaceWith($("#badTopic6"));
                $("#goodTopic7").replaceWith($("#badTopic7"));
                $("#goodTopic8").replaceWith($("#badTopic8"));
            });
            // Changes the about the page text
            $('.change-text').each(function () {
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Hello and welcome to (insert name here). Here you are able to see unbiased opinions on the current several current happenings of the world. There is a collection of eight good and bad events that have occurred in our recent history and we would like to share the correct information on the matters.',
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu sed duis harum. Ex eam congue ponderum electram, nec elit graecis eu, error dolore mandamus nec at. At ullum facilisis eum. In sea consequat incorrupte, viris facilis ad vel. Eos no diceret recusabo, mei et soleat postulant philosophia, cibo libris omnium an mea.');
            });
        });
```

> This is the new code that I'm sure there is an correct and much simplier way of doing

```
$('body').on('click', '#change-page', function () {
        var element = $("#bg-carousel");

    if(element.css('background-color') == "#e54f31") {

        $('.color-div').each(function () {
                $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('color1'));
            });
            // Changes the topics
            $('#badTopic1, #badTopic2, #badTopic3, #badTopic4, #badTopic5, #badTopic6, #badTopic7, #badTopic8').each(function () {
                $('#goodTopic1, #goodTopic2, #goodTopic3, #goodTopic4, #goodTopic5, #goodTopic6, #goodTopic7, #goodTopic8').hide();
                $('#badTopic1, #badTopic2, #badTopic3, #badTopic4, #badTopic5, #badTopic6, #badTopic7, #badTopic8').show();
                $("#goodTopic1").replaceWith($("#badTopic1"));
                $("#goodTopic2").replaceWith($("#badTopic2"));
                $("#goodTopic3").replaceWith($("#badTopic3"));
                $("#goodTopic4").replaceWith($("#badTopic4"));
                $("#goodTopic5").replaceWith($("#badTopic5"));
                $("#goodTopic6").replaceWith($("#badTopic6"));
                $("#goodTopic7").replaceWith($("#badTopic7"));
                $("#goodTopic8").replaceWith($("#badTopic8"));
            });
            // Changes the about the page text
            $('.change-text').each(function () {
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat');
            });
    }

    else {

        $('.color-div').each(function () {
                $(this).css('background-color', $(this).data('color'));
            });
            // Changes the topics
            $('#goodTopic1, #goodTopic2, #goodTopic3, #goodTopic4, #goodTopic5, #goodTopic6, #goodTopic7, #goodTopic8').each(function () {
                $('#badTopic1, #badTopic2, #badTopic3, #badTopic4, #badTopic5, #badTopic6, #badTopic7, #badTopic8').hide();
                $('#goodTopic1, #goodTopic2, #goodTopic3, #goodTopic4, #goodTopic5, #goodTopic6, #goodTopic7, #goodTopic8').show();
                $("#badTopic1").replaceWith($("#goodTopic1"));
                $("#badTopic2").replaceWith($("#goodTopic2"));
                $("#badTopic3").replaceWith($("#goodTopic3"));
                $("#badTopic4").replaceWith($("#goodTopic4"));
                $("#badTopic5").replaceWith($("#goodTopic5"));
                $("#badTopic6").replaceWith($("#goodTopic6"));
                $("#badTopic7").replaceWith($("#goodTopic7"));
                $("#badTopic8").replaceWith($("#goodTopic8"));
            });
            // Changes the about the page text
            $('.change-text').each(function () {
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Hello and welcome to (insert name here). Here you are able to see unbiased opinions on the current several current happenings of the world. There is a collection of eight good and bad events that have occurred in our recent history and we would like to share the correct information on the matters.',
                    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu sed duis harum. Ex eam congue ponderum electram, nec elit graecis eu, error dolore mandamus nec at. At ullum facilisis eum. In sea consequat incorrupte, viris facilis ad vel. Eos no diceret recusabo, mei et soleat postulant philosophia, cibo libris omnium an mea.');
            });
    }
        });
```

> This is what it looks like before

[image]

> This is what it looks like afterclick the colors and text change but the divs dont. It keeps the first divs but doesn't hide them and I think it moves the other set of divs into position it just keeps them hidden. The biggest problem is that it doesn't let the user switch back.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way, by just adding a couple divs to hold your two views:

```
     ...
    <li class="filter btn btn-primary" data-filter=".branding">POLITICS</li>
    <li class="filter btn btn-primary" data-filter=".design">ETHICS</li>
    <li class="filter btn btn-primary" data-filter=".development">MISCALULATIONS</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id='view1'>
  <div class="mix branding col-md-3" id="goodTopic1">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/projects/project1.png" />
        <a href="#project-1"> ...
          ...
</div>
<div id='view2'>
  <div class="mix development col-md-3" id="badTopic1">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/backfiletest.png" />
        <a href="#project-2"> ...
         ...
</div>
```

Then, in your JS making view1 disappear and view2 appear would be as simple as

```
$('view1').css('display','block'); $('view2').css('display','none');
```

Then, swap them back:

```
$('view2').css('display','block'); $('view1').css('display','none');
```

There's no replacing, so nothing is ever lost.

Comment: It didn't seem to work when I tried it also how would I impliment it to help with switching the background colors which are stored within data-color and data-color1

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code, I can't tell you why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Well since I've posted this the question I've changed it a lot and I just cant seem to get it to work I've tried like sooooo many Jquery stuff, restructured it and now its a bit of a mess. Would you mind takin a look?